# Set Function show/hide button in slow speed jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, set this function show/hide button in  slow speed:

```
<button id="trmtn" onclick="trclick(this);"><span id="nod_trmtn">[+]</span>File</button>
```

File hide:

```
<div id="bd_trmtn" style="display: none">
HELLO!
</div>
```

This function:

```
var d = document;
function trclick(a){
    var view,valbt;
    var c=d.getElementById('bd_'+a.id);
    var e=d.getElementById('nod_'+a.id);
    view=c.style.display;c.style.display=(view==''?'none':'');
    valbt=(view==''?'[+]':'[-]');
    e.innerHTML=valbt;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? What do you mean by 'slow motion'.

Comment: @franco, show file hidden slow speed.

Comment: You want to use the jQuery functions? You don't seem to be using any of the jQuery functions for it.

Comment: @ness-rosales, jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Is the use of  ' jQuery' an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery makes this easy to do. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f92vczpm/

HTML:

```
<button id="trmtn"><span id="nod_trmtn">[+]</span>File</button>
<div id="bd_trmtn" style="display:none;">
HELLO!
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#trmtn').click(function(){
    // get the ID of the button that was clicked
    var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
    // determine if your button will have a plus or minus after the toggle
    spanText = $('#bd_' + thisID).is(':visible') ? "[+]": "[-]";
    // get a reference to the span tag so you can update it in the callback function
    span = $(this).find('span');
    // toggle the div with speed of "slow" for slow motion. then use callback function to change the button text
    $('#bd_' + thisID).slideToggle("slow", function(){ $(span).text(spanText); });
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it has to be as a function because I will use in various buttons with different id.

Comment: You can just as easily create it as a function and pass the button object to it. function toggleMe(btn) { var thisID = $(btn).attr('id'); etc... Or, you could add a class to all of your buttons like "class="toggleBtn" then use that to trigger the function $('.toggleBtn').click(function(){ var thisID = $(this).attr('id'); etc... personally I'd just add the class to the button. Here's a fiddle showing that one working: http://jsfiddle.net/f92vczpm/1/

Comment: And here's the same thing as a function with the onclick handler in the button. http://jsfiddle.net/f92vczpm/2/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include a version of jQuery for this.

```
$('selector').hide(speed,callback);
$('selector').show(speed,callback);
```

For Example to animate its disappearance (slowly)

```
$('element').hide(1000);
```

Or

```
$("element").hide('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` you can do it like following. `fadeIn()` shows and `fadeOut()` hides the element through the given time. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('#trmtn').click(function(){
    var bd = $('#bd_trmtn');
    if(!bd.is(':visible')){
        bd.fadeIn(2000); //take 2s to show
        $(this).find('#nod_trmtn').html('[-]');
    }else{
        bd.fadeOut(2000); //take 2s to hide
        $(this).find('#nod_trmtn').html('[+]');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="trmtn"><span id="nod_trmtn">[+]</span>File</button>
<div id="bd_trmtn" style="display: none">
     HELLO!
</div>
```